# Can Selenium WebDriver access files on Google Drive?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I want to store my Selenium WebDriver test case files on Google Drive so I can run them from work and from home. I'm using Java as my programming language in Selenium 2.

How can I point Selenium 2 to Google Drive files?

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start by using the [Google Drive SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/java), you'll need to load tests from the **Google Drive** and then run them. You might want to read up on [ClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html). And you could also use [ClassLoader.defineClass()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#defineClass%28java.lang.String,%20byte%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29) and then [Class.newInstance()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29). Look at their example `NetworkClassLoader`.

Comment: +1, Google has done well to provide clear API's for this in many languages, no need *at all* to access this through the UI.